# Componente Carousel - Ajustar imagem dentro do Carousel

Tags: react, typescript, carousel

Criei um componente Carousel em React e um componente Banner onde estou consumindo o Carousel, coloquei 4 imagens dentro do meu componente banner, porém, não consigo fazer com que todas as imagens ocupem 100% do carousel, alguma dica?

Componente Carousel:

```
return (
<CarouselContainer>
  <Slide
    onTransitionEnd={handleTransitionEnd}
    className={transitioning ? 'transitioning' : ''}
    style={{
      width: `${slides.length * 100}%`,
      transform: `translateX(-${(currentIndex * 100) / slides.length}%)`,
    }}
  >
    {slides.map((slide, index) => (
      <div key={index} style={{ width: `${100 / slides.length}%` }}>
        {slide}
      </div>
    ))}
  </Slide>
  <button onClick={goToPrevSlide}>Anterior</button>
  <button onClick={goToNextSlide}>Próximo</button>
</CarouselContainer>
);
```

Estou utilizando Styled.components:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const CarouselContainer = styled.div`
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
`;

export const Slide = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;

  &.transitioning {
    transition: none;
  }

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  }

  .hidden {
    opacity: 0;
  }
`;
```

Preciso que minha imagem ocupe todo o espaço em vermelho:
[Print de como fica o banner no carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EguVf.jpg)

Este é meu Banner:

```
  const Banner = () => {
  const slides = [
    <img src={banner1} alt="Slide 1" />,
    <img src={banner2} alt="Slide 2" />,
    <img src={banner3} alt="Slide 3" />,
    <img src={banner4} alt="Slide 4" />,
  ];

  return (
    <BannerContainer>
      <Carousel
        slides={slides}
        autoPlay={false}
        delay={5000}
      />
    </BannerContainer>
  );
};

export default Banner;

    export const BannerContainer = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 32px;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
`;
```